# Maven could not resolve dependencies for project from mutiple mirrors

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-assembly-plugin

In our project we are using maven to download artifacts from multiple mirrors.

When I am giving the maven build,maven is downloading the artifacts from the first mirror only.If any artifacts are missing in first mirror it is downloading from second mirror and the build is getting failed.Please find the below settings.xml file.

settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>c:\.m2</localRepository>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
        --&gt;
        <pluginGroup>com.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
    <proxies />
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>rix-site</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>gatho7</username>
            <password>gatho7</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>releases</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>itf-central-nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>ITF central repo</name>
            <url>http://ikolplm.greak.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus-rix</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>Ebcdev mirror</name>
            <url>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <!-- EBCManager WAS8 -->
        <profile>
            <id>ebcmanager</id>
            <properties>
                <ebcmanager.url>http://XXXXXX.XXXXX/EBCManager</ebcmanager.url>
                <ebcmanager.username>username</ebcmanager.username>
                <ebcmanager.password>pasword</ebcmanager.password>
                <ebcmanager.node>mme.iop.com</ebcmanager.node>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <properties>
                <release.deployment.repository>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</release.deployment.repository>
                <snapshot.deployment.repository>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</snapshot.deployment.repository>
                <nexus.repository>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</nexus.repository>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <mfs.scm.url>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081</mfs.scm.url>
                <rsm.skip>false</rsm.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>rix-nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>rix-nexus</id>
                    <url>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>rix-nexus</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>pos-obc-parent</artifactId>
    <name>pos-obc-parent</name>
    <version>1.41.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ieak.obcdevelopmentkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-obc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <!-- pos core libraries version-->
        <pos.core.version>1.41.0-SNAPSHOT</pos.core.version>
        <!-- pos obc core modules version -->
        <pos.core.obc.version>1.41.0-SNAPSHOT</pos.core.obc.version>
        <eclipse.workspace>C:\\workspace\\pos_eclipse\\pos-develop</eclipse.workspace>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <clearcase.integration.skip>true</clearcase.integration.skip>
        <wobclassifier>classes</wobclassifier>
        <!-- Test versions -->
        <spring-test-dbunit.version>1.0.1</spring-test-dbunit.version>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>pos Releases</name>
            <url>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>pos Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posjavacommon</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posjavacommon</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posrangedomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posrangedomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posrangeitemdomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posrangeitemdomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posscpdomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posscpdomainmodel</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ieak.obcposcommon01</groupId>
                <artifactId>obcposcommon01</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.obc.version}</version>
                <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ieak.obcposcommon01</groupId>
                <artifactId>obcposcommon01</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.obc.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
                <artifactId>posrangedomainmodelabstract</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ieak.obcpospim01</groupId>
                <artifactId>obcpospim01</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.obc.version}</version>
                <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ieak.obcposscp01</groupId>
                <artifactId>obcposscp01</artifactId>
                <version>${pos.core.obc.version}</version>
                <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Test dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-test-dbunit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <profiles>
        <!-- See https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki/ How-do-I-add-my-web-project-classes-to-another-project-classpath%3F -->
        <profile>
            <id>m2e</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>m2e.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <wobclassifier />
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>codequality</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Attach source code artifact -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.1</version>
                        <!-- Doesn't work when not internet connected -->
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>validate</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/pos-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <suppressionsLocation>${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/pos-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                            <!-- <headerLocation>${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/pos-java-header.txt</headerLocation> -->
                            <propertiesLocation>${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/pos-checkstyle.properties</propertiesLocation>
                            <propertyExpansion>basedir=${basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                            <enableRSS>false</enableRSS>
                            <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                            <enableRulesSummary>false</enableRulesSummary>
                            <consoleOutput>false</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                            <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                            <enableRulesSummary>true</enableRulesSummary>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>pmd</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                            <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                            <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                            <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
                            <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                            <propertyExpansion>basedir=${basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <rulesets>
                                <ruleset>${basedir}/build-tools/pmd/pos-pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                            </rulesets>
                            <excludeRoots>
                                <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/stubs</excludeRoot>
                            </excludeRoots>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.range.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>pos-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <addGroupIdToProjectName>false</addGroupIdToProjectName>
                        <useProjectReferences>true</useProjectReferences>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>build-tools</directory>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>resource-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <includeGroupIds>com.range.domain</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>pos-build-tools</includeArtifactIds>
                            <includes>**/checkstyle/**,**/pmd/**</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/build-tools</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Eclipse configurations -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>true</useProjectReferences>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <addGroupIdToProjectName>false</addGroupIdToProjectName>
                    <workspace>${eclipse.workspace}</workspace>
                    <workspaceCodeStylesURL>file:///${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/pos-formatter.xml</workspaceCodeStylesURL>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.xls</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.xml</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.jpg</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.gif</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.bmp</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.txt</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.properties</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.bin</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.vm</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdBuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>net.sourceforge.pmd.runtime.pmdNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.checkstyle</name>
                            <location>${basedir}/build-tools/checkstyle/eclipse-checkstyle.xml</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.ruleset</name>
                            <location>${basedir}/build-tools/pmd/pos-pmd-ruleset.xml</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.pmd</name>
                            <location>${basedir}/build-tools/pmd/eclipse-pmd.xml</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs</name>
                            <content><![CDATA[eclipse.preferences.version=1${line.separator}encoding/<project>=${project.build.sourceEncoding}${line.separator}]]></content>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <!-- The java framework version will be the same as the pos-obc-parent's parent since 
                                    that is how the dependency to the framework is specified. -->
                            <JavaFramework-Version>${project.parent.parent.version}</JavaFramework-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: please share relevant logs to failure.

Comment: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.XXX.XXX:XXX-XXX-parent:1.41.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.XXX.eXXXXXXkit:parent-ebc:pom:7.0.0 in http://kjuiopl-bw00098:8081/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-rix has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 10

Comment: Must share the pom.xml along with this detail in the question itself.

Comment: share pom.xml file

Comment: please look specifically for `relativePath` as the logs suggest in your project or its parent pom.xml

Comment: First of all are you sure the artefact maven is looking for, is present in one of the repositories? i'm talking about parent-ebc:pom:7.0.0, can you also try to clean the .m2 local repository and rerun the build?